# Getting code to break inside a C# if statement in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the debugger to stop at a line by using the

```
  Debug.Break()
```

But all this seems to do is pause the unity editor. My IDE doesn't stop.

I know my IDE is attached as a debugger because if I place a breakpoint in the Update method then it stops.

I am trying to do something like this

```
if (movespeed >10 ) {
    Debug.Break(); // Needs to stop debugger on this line
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just put the breakpoint in your IDE inside the if block.

Comment: I don't know unity, but in regular .NET, Debugger.Break() can be used for that.

Comment: Yep, Debugger.Break() doesn't seem to work

Comment: @jeanluc, yes, this of course would work but I am trying to force the debugger to stop, in normal c# you can do this. I thought it would be possible in unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name can be misleading, but `Debug.Break` doesn't stop the debugger.

According the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Break.html):

> **Debug.Break**
>
> `public static void Break();`
>
> Description
>
> Pauses the editor.
>
> This is useful when you want to check certain values on the inspector
>   and you are not able to pause it manually.

Comment: Is it possible to stop the debugger then with something else ?

Comment: as far as I know, the only way to stop the debugger is with a breakpoint. In case that you need stop the debugger under certain conditions you can add some conditional logic to that breakpoint. another option is throwing an exception, something like `throw new UnityException()`